# How to retrieve the address from latitude and longitude in firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code.In firebase i have saved my latitude and longitude.Now I want to retrieve that latitude and longitude from the firebase and show in the addreesstv text box.But my code is not working .App is crashing.What should I change?

```
private void loadAddress() {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name=""+dataSnapshot.child("mylocation").child("name2").getValue();

            lattitude= Double.parseDouble(""+dataSnapshot.child("mylocation").child("latitude").getValue());
            longitude= Double.parseDouble(""+dataSnapshot.child("mylocation").child("longitude").getValue());

            Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> addresses;
            geocoder=new Geocoder(MainUserActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

            try{
                addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(lattitude,longitude,1);
                String address=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String city=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                String state=addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String country=addresses.get(0).getCountryName();

                addresstv.setText(address);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainUserActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    };
    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
2020-07-23 18:38:43.237 25598-25598/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myproject.marutiApp, PID: 25598
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.myproject.marutiApp.MainUserActivity$1.onDataChange(MainUserActivity.java:83)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

2020-07-23 18:38:43.298 25598-25598/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25598 SIG: 9

Comment: What is the error in logcat?

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` You try to get the first element (index 0) from an empty list (size 0).

Comment: It said that there is an error in try and catch part.If I commented that whole part.App is not crashing.But full address is not showing as well.

Comment: can anyone give me the correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `getFromLocation` returns an empty list. To prevent the error, you'll need to detect that there are no results, and in that case not set it on `addresstv`.

So something like:

```
addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(lattitude,longitude,1);
if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
    String address=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String city=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    String state=addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
    String country=addresses.get(0).getCountryName();

    addresstv.setText(address);
}
```

Comment: addresses.length is highlighted with red.How to solve that? .length part is highlighted.Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: After inspecting the API doc for [`GeoCoder.getFromLocation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) it seems that returns a [`List`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List). In that case use `size()` to determine the size of the list. I updated the code in my answer, but also highly recommend learning to navigate the API docs, as it will help you get yourself unstuck when an answer like mine doesn't 1:1 apply to your situation.